# If and or operator django admin models

Tags: python, django, admin

Im trying to make some kind of logic function  " sufficient_information_provided " which returns boolean. As for now im new to python syntax.. i would appreciate if anyone could help figure this out,  here is the model in django app

```
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    family_group = models.ForeignKey(FamilyGroup,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    relationship = models.ForeignKey(Relationship, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    dependant_child_age_range = models.ForeignKey(DependantChildAgeRange,
                                            null=True,
                                            blank=True,
                                            on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    care_percentage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True, validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),
        ]
    )
    income = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,
                            decimal_places=2,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True)
```

And here is the function in same .py folder

```
@property
def sufficient_information_provided(self):
    b = ('Tenant', 'Partner')
    if (
        self.name and
        self.date_of_birth and
        self.relationship and(
            (
            self.relationship.name not in b and
                self.dependant_child_age_range
            ) or (
                self.relationship.name in b and
                self.income
            )
        ) 
    ): 
        return True
    return False
```

What i'm trying to do is:

- when `relationship.name` not in the tuple and `dependant_age_range` is not `None`
- and when `relationship.name` is in the tuple and `self.income` is not `None`

It returns `True` else returns `False`.

[here is how the admin looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nlff.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For code clarity, you can use a combination of `all` and `any`:

- `all` will return `True` if all elements of the iterable return `True`.
- `any` will return `True` if at least one element of the iterable returns `True`.

So your function – I just copied the algorithm without questioning it - could look like:

```
def sufficient_information_provided(self):
    b = ["Tenant", "Partner"]

    return all(
        [
            self.name,
            self.date_of_birth,
            self.relationship,
            any(
                [
                    (
                        self.relationship.name not in b
                        and self.dependant_child_age_range
                    ),
                    (self.relationship.name in b and self.income),
                ]
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the sufficient information provided < 3